# A more positive word for "co-conspirator"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

I'm trying to write a sentence like **"Be your own fairy godmother"**, but I don't know if it really works.

The advice I'm trying to give (within a larger context not shared here) is that a woman can act as her own co-conspirator (but without the negative connotation of that word) to arrange/coordinate various factors in her favor so that she can meet and fall in love with the man of her dreams.

I don't *really* feel that any of the words in the following list really convey what I'm aiming for, but maybe "fairy godmother" is the closest (and other bold ones are better than non-bold).

Do you have any additional suggestions or thoughts?

- accomplice
- **advocate**
- ally
- associate
- **benefactor**
- champion
- co-conspirator
- collaborator
- colleague
- confederate
- cooperator
- enthusiast
- **fairy godmother**
- guarantor
- guardian
- helper
- insider
- partner
- **patron**
- patron saint
- philanthropist
- **proponent**
- sponsor
- supporter
- teammate

Comment: Specifically in the context of finding the love interest of your dreams, I think "fairy godmother" is probably the best you'll find, or maybe *matchmaker*. Otherwise, if none of the terms you've listed work you might want to look at more hierarchical terms like *mastermind* or *coach* or *personal assistant* and their synonyms.

Comment: It's funny that "matchmaker" didn't occur to me. Good thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this exact context a relatively modern phrase may be apt

> **be your own [wingman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingman_(social)).**

Also **guardian angel** carries a similar sense as fairy godmother.

Comment: It's funny that I didn't think of "wingman"! Maybe because I'm speaking to women, and "wingwoman" isn't as common of a term. But it's still an interesting suggestion, as is "guardian angel". Thanks.